# how can I use JavaScript to search every field in a list for specific text

Tags: 2013, javascript, search

I have an SP list with an arbitrary number of fields. I know how to use CAML and REST to get list items and filter where a specific field matches a specific string. I was wondering if there is anyway to search *every* field for specific text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look at the Search API : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview

Edit: because you don't index your list, then you have to use the CAML query for each field with a OR and CONTAINS. However you'll be limited by the kind of your fields: It will work with Text fields.

The other possible solution is to load your entire list into a javascript object, and then to apply the search on your javascript object and return only the relevant items (without interacting with the server). There are [plenty of JS library](https://www.google.fr/search?q=js%20search%20library) to help you with that. In my experience, loading a full list is very fast so the performance should be OK (except if your list has thousands of records).

Comment: So our company doesn't do the back-end indexing required for the built-in search function to work properly. This is why we cannot use the built-in search on an SP site. I was trying to hack something together with JS...

Comment: I've edited my answer

Comment: Unfortunately some of our lists do have thousands of records. I guess I can use CAML but I hate that I have to pull the list details first to find all the fields that I can search to build the query. Thanks!